# Why does the ouput of an NC0 circuit depend on only a constant number of input bits?

Tags: complexity-theory, trees, binary-trees, circuits

I understand that NC0 circuits have a constant depth and bounded gate fan-in of two, but I'm struggling how to understand why the language is in NC0 iff there is a constant c such that for every n, there is a set c variables that determine it's membership.

Answer (score 2):

An $\mathsf{NC}^0$ circuit *with single output* of depth $\ell$ has $O(2^\ell)$ nodes, and in particular can depend on at most $O(2^\ell)$ many input bits.

$\mathsf{NC}^0$ circuits become more interesting when we allow them to have many outputs. Amazingly, there are some things you can actually do with some circuits. Check out the classic paper [Crypography in $\mathsf{NC}^0$](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~yuvali/pubs/AIK04full.pdf) by Applebaum, Ishai, and Kushilevitz.